# ContextNotActiveException while calling entityManger.createNativeQuery using thread

Tags: java, jpa, threadpool, entitymanager

> I have started a thread but when it try to access entity Manager it throws exception as 
>   javax.enterprise.context.ContextNotActiveException: 
>   WebBeans context with scope type annotation @RequestScoped does not exist within current thread
>
> How should I access EntityManger with thread
>   any solution?

```
 public class SchedulerForData {
        @Inject
        private DefaultUserSevice userSevice;


        public void beepForAnHour() {
            long initialDelay;
            final Runnable beeper = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                         userSevice.getData();
                         }
            scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, 60, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        }
        }
    }



    public class DefaultUserSevice {

    @Inject
    EntityManager entityManger;


    public void getData(){
      List resultList = entityManager.createNativeQuery("Select * from USER").getResultList();
    }

    }
```

Comment: are there any annotations on the DefaultUserSevice class?

Comment: No annotations Sir

Answer (score 0):

If there is no other configuration on the service, you should make the service a managed bean and add transactional feature:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class DefaultUserSevice
```

Comment: I used above annotation but it throws exception at entityManger.createNativeQuery() but I cannot see any kind of exception or error on console

Comment: No sir because its cannot proceed ahead